# Python Buffer API image upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, social-media

I'm trying to work with Buffer API and buffer a tweet with an image. In [documentation](https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates#updatescreate) it says to pass the image link in media[] associative array as an argument for POST request. But what if I want to upload a local image? I tried an absolute and a relative paths to the local file but it doesn't work. I get an 'invalid image parameter supplied' error. Here is my code.

```
POST_IMG = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + r'\output.jpg'
data={'profile_ids[]': twitter_id, 'text': 'Twitter text', 'media[photo]': POST_IMG}
requests.post(f'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/updates/create.json?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}', data=data)
```

Comment: What does `print(POST_IMG)` return if you place it after the `POST_IMG` variable definition?

Comment: An absolute path to the image on my PC

c:\Users\Glut\Documents\GitHub\illustration-on-the-edge\output.jpg

Comment: My assumption is that unless you have a an open port that is accessible by a website on the internet, it will tell you your link is invalid. It probably checks if your link starts with http/https, and if  not it knows your image is not hosted online. “Users/.../“ doesnt mean anything to a website hosted online, thats why it needs a full, open port URL

Comment: I see. Anyway, thanks. I think I'll try another solution. Just found out about cloudinary. Maybe that way I'll be able to do everything online through APIs only, without storing images locally.